# How to integrate the function A^2 * Cos[ (1/A) * B * Exp[-c * (x-D)^2 ] ]

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can someone help me with the following integration. Thank you.

\begin{equation}
\int_{L1}^{L2}  dx \quad A^2 \cos\left[ \frac{B \exp\{-C (x-D)^2 \}}{A} \right],
\end{equation}

I tried Mathematica online integrator which could not do this.

This is not a home work problem. I just wondered how integrals of these sorts are done. I added the constants to get a general formula. I have a solution based on Taylor expansion of the cosine function which looks a bit messy. I wonder if there are some standard solutions for this integral.

Comment: Is it homework? Any particular reason you expect it to have a closed form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $A,B,C\neq0$ for the key case:

$\int_{L_1}^{L_2}A^2\cos\dfrac{Be^{-C(x-D)^2}}{A}dx$

$=\int_{L_1-D}^{L_2-D}A^2\cos\dfrac{Be^{-Cx^2}}{A}dx$

$=\int_{L_1-D}^{L_2-D}A^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nB^{2n}e^{-2nCx^2}}{A^{2n}(2n)!}dx$

$=\int_{L_1-D}^{L_2-D}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nB^{2n}e^{-2nCx^2}}{A^{2n-2}(2n)!}dx$

$=\int_{L_1-D}^{L_2-D}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}2^kn^kB^{2n}C^kx^{2k}}{A^{2n-2}(2n)!k!}dx$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}2^kn^kB^{2n}C^kx^{2k+1}}{A^{2n-2}(2n)!k!(2k+1)}\right]_{L_1-D}^{L_2-D}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}2^kn^kB^{2n}C^k((L_2-D)^{2k+1}-(L_1-D)^{2k+1})}{A^{2n-2}(2n)!k!(2k+1)}$